# "curses.h: No such file or directory" even after installing into Cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin, curses

I'm working on a C clone of the 2048 game, using curses.h for the UI.  When trying to compile it with Cygwin using the make commanad, I get following message:

```
PS D:\C\ps3> make all
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -g  -c main.c -lm -lcurses -o main.o
main.c:4:20: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory
#include <curses.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:13: main.o] Error 1
```

So I ran the setup again, looking for any package that has "curses" in it's name and installed it, added my /bin folder to the PATH variable but it didn't help.

I'm working on a 64-bit Win10 and trying to compile the program with Cygwin's terminal, using a Makefile. file. I've tried reinstalling the packages with curses in their name multiple times with no help.

Part of my Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c11 -Wall -Werror -g 
LDLIBS=-lm -lcurses
OUTPUT=game

# targets
all: $(OUTPUT)

$(OUTPUT): k.o  hof.o main.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) k.o hof.o main.o $(LDLIBS) -o $(OUTPUT)

main.o: main.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c $(LDLIBS) -o main.o
```

The line in main.c the error is pointing to:

```
#include "hof.h"
#include "k.h"
#include "ui.h"
#include <curses.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

The header file would be in ***libncurses-devel*** (perhaps overlooked).  Here's a screenshot showing the "curses" packages which I have in my local repository:

[image: screenshot of cygwin installer]